# javax.sip.OUTBOUND_PROXY is ignored when Router Header is added

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

I'm working in a SIP Project

I alredy set up the OUTBOUND_PROXY like

myProperties.setProperty("javax.sip.OUTBOUND_PROXY", "pcscf.infotelims.test:4060/udp");

But When I send the send a request with RouteHeader, The request ignor the OUTBOUND_PROXY and send it throught RouteHeader.

The route header is created like:

Address routeAddress = myAddressFactory.createAddress("sip:orig@scscf.infotelims.test:6060");
        SipURI myrouteURI = (SipURI) routeAddress.getURI(); 
        myrouteURI.setLrParam();
        myRouteHeader = myHeaderFactory.createRouteHeader(myAddressFactory.createAddress(myrouteURI));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe matches the description for `DefaultRouter` with `javax.sip.USE_ROUTER_FOR_ALL_URIS=false`, as shown [in this link](http://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/jain-sip/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/javadoc/gov/nist/javax/sip/stack/DefaultRouter.html).  The `Route` header takes priority over the outbound proxy setting.

It looks like if you set the property above to `true`, all requests will go to the configured proxy address.  Another approach would be to push *two* `Route` headers onto the request.